# nGModelController.$render not called even after setting value through $setViewValue

Tags: angular-ngmodel

I recently learned of the ngModelController, and had been experimenting with it. My directive is an input field and on  its keydown, I set the value of the model as ngModelController.$setViewValue. It should call the $render as written in the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and explained in this [blog](http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/). But the $render in the code below, is not called. Please suggest.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GRJsBILy7JumkdeWlHmP?p=preview)

## Angular Code

```
angular.module('controls',[]);

angular.module('controls')
.controller('Spinner',['$scope',
        function($scope){
            $scope.spinner="";
        }
])
.directive('spinControl',function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'spin.html',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope,elem,attrs,ngModelController){
            ngModelController.$render = function() {
                alert('render called');
            };

            elem.on('keyup', function(event){
                ngModelController.$setViewValue(elem.find('input').val());
            });
        }
    };
});
```

P.S. - I tried to find similar question on SO, but couldn't find it. Guide me to the question if its duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`$render` is called when the external model value gets changed outside your directive. `$setViewValue` won't trigger it (because it's assumed that, since your view was what changed, that the needed changes are already rendered).

If you have `<spin-control ng-model="spinner"></spin-control>`, then try putting this in the Spinner controller:

```
$timeout(function () { 
    $scope.spinner = 'new value';
}, 1000);
```

(remember to inject `$timeout` into your controller). 1000 seconds after your controller loads your `alert()` should show up.